# You are not authenticated! Error code: 0 exception occurred only for UiPath background process

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

I started a development using the UiPath template called ‘Background Process’ and currently I’m facing an issue when reading orchestrator assets. It throws the error ‘You are not authenticated! Error code: 0’. But when I tried out UiPath RE-Framework based developments, this issue was not emerged. However I’m using the community editions of both studio and the orchestrator where the version is 2021.10.5. I’ve been struggling for whole 1 day trying out different solutions, but failed. No idea whether there is something with background processes or not. I would really appreciate your support ahead in time.

Image 1 - Normal flow without using either RE Framework or Background process
[image]

Image 2 - RE Framework process
[image]

Image 3 - Background process
[image]

Image 4 - The main file of background process
[image]

Comment: Good question. When I was using the `Background Process` in the past, I also had issues. This might be because the process is using another system user of Windows. But in your case, this sounds different. Can you share a screenshot of the same activities of a Background Process and a Regular Process? Did you already test without the RE Framework? So we can better compare what is missing. Maybe a scope is missing?

Comment: @kwoxer Thank you and yes I have checked without RE Framework as well. I have something to highlight in your answer. What did you mean by 'scope is missing'? Is it something to be added specially in background processes? I have added few screenshots for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted out the issue by downgrading "UIPath.System.Activities" version into 20.4.0.
Thank you.

Comment: Interesting and definitely worth reporting it as a bug. Thank you.